# Resource and asset merger: '-' is not a valid file-based resource name character:

Tags: javascript, react-native

react-native project build strang issue. i have resources name like `abc-def.png` , `map-maker.png` it giving me the below error .

```
Resource and asset merger: '-' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore
```

the project was working fine before i have just created a new project and copy the source code.

Here are the logs.

```
D:\Repos\family_tracker>npx react-native start --reset-cache

                        ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒
                     ▒▓▓▓▒▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▒
                  ▒▓▓▓▓░░░▒▒▒▒░░░▓▓▓▓▒
                 ▓▓▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▓▓
                 ▓▓░░░░░▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░░░▓▓
                 ▓▓░░▓▓▒░░░▒▒░░░▒▓▒░░▓▓
                 ▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▒▒▓▓▓▓▒░░▓▓
                 ▓▓░░▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░▓▓
                 ▓▓▒░░▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓
                  ▒▓▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓▒░░░▒▓▓▓▒
                     ▒▓▓▓▒░░░░▒▓▓▓▒
                        ▒▒▓▓▓▓▒▒


warning: the transform cache was reset.
                Welcome to Metro v0.76.5
              Fast - Scalable - Integrated

r - reload the app
d - open developer menu
i - run on iOS
a - run on Android

info Opening the app on Android...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE

> Configure project :app
No flavor mapping detected. Reading injected file
Root config [MAP_API:AIzaSyBWFMjBnMaz4rO8mvQDZlczD8yTUKBRllE, SERVER_URL:https://familylocation.phonetracker.live, PROFILE_URL:https://familylocation.phonetracker.live/tracking/uploads/images/, GROUOP_PROFILE:https://familylocation.phonetracker.live/tracking/uploads/groupImages/, WEB_CLIENT_ID:383543943528-4ui5qug270oj5mns4003hufmggcjkec9.apps.googleusercontent.com, ADMOB_APPLICATION_ID:ca-app-pub-9498660037072845~8691014902, ADMOB_NATIVE_AD_ID:ca-app-pub-9498660037072845/8116299832, ADMOB_INSTERTIAL_AD_ID:ca-app-pub-9498660037072845/1883091644, ADMOB_APP_OPEN_AD_ID:ca-app-pub-9498660037072845/6286313038]
processing variant debug
mapping does not exist or flavor is not defined
config per flavor  [MAP_API:AIzaSyBWFMjBnMaz4rO8mvQDZlczD8yTUKBRllE, SERVER_URL:https://familylocation.phonetracker.live, PROFILE_URL:https://familylocation.phonetracker.live/tracking/uploads/images/, GROUOP_PROFILE:https://familylocation.phonetracker.live/tracking/uploads/groupImages/, WEB_CLIENT_ID:383543943528-4ui5qug270oj5mns4003hufmggcjkec9.apps.googleusercontent.com, ADMOB_APPLICATION_ID:ca-app-pub-9498660037072845~8691014902, ADMOB_NATIVE_AD_ID:ca-app-pub-9498660037072845/8116299832, ADMOB_INSTERTIAL_AD_ID:ca-app-pub-9498660037072845/1883091644, ADMOB_APP_OPEN_AD_ID:ca-app-pub-9498660037072845/6286313038]
all keys [MAP_API, SERVER_URL, PROFILE_URL, GROUOP_PROFILE, WEB_CLIENT_ID, ADMOB_APPLICATION_ID, ADMOB_NATIVE_AD_ID, ADMOB_INSTERTIAL_AD_ID, ADMOB_APP_OPEN_AD_ID]
all keys as string MAP_API,SERVER_URL,PROFILE_URL,GROUOP_PROFILE,WEB_CLIENT_ID,ADMOB_APPLICATION_ID,ADMOB_NATIVE_AD_ID,ADMOB_INSTERTIAL_AD_ID,ADMOB_APP_OPEN_AD_ID
processing variant release
mapping does not exist or flavor is not defined
config per flavor  [MAP_API:AIzaSyBWFMjBnMaz4rO8mvQDZlczD8yTUKBRllE, SERVER_URL:https://familylocation.phonetracker.live, PROFILE_URL:https://familylocation.phonetracker.live/tracking/uploads/images/, GROUOP_PROFILE:https://familylocation.phonetracker.live/tracking/uploads/groupImages/, WEB_CLIENT_ID:383543943528-4ui5qug270oj5mns4003hufmggcjkec9.apps.googleusercontent.com, ADMOB_APPLICATION_ID:ca-app-pub-9498660037072845~8691014902, ADMOB_NATIVE_AD_ID:ca-app-pub-9498660037072845/8116299832, ADMOB_INSTERTIAL_AD_ID:ca-app-pub-9498660037072845/1883091644, ADMOB_APP_OPEN_AD_ID:ca-app-pub-9498660037072845/6286313038]
all keys [MAP_API, SERVER_URL, PROFILE_URL, GROUOP_PROFILE, WEB_CLIENT_ID, ADMOB_APPLICATION_ID, ADMOB_NATIVE_AD_ID, ADMOB_INSTERTIAL_AD_ID, ADMOB_APP_OPEN_AD_ID]
all keys as string MAP_API,SERVER_URL,PROFILE_URL,GROUOP_PROFILE,WEB_CLIENT_ID,ADMOB_APPLICATION_ID,ADMOB_NATIVE_AD_ID,ADMOB_INSTERTIAL_AD_ID,ADMOB_APP_OPEN_AD_ID

> Configure project :notifee_react-native
:notifee_react-native @notifee/react-native found at D:\Repos\family_tracker\node_modules\@notifee\react-native
:notifee_react-native package.json found at D:\Repos\family_tracker\node_modules\@notifee\react-native\package.json
:notifee_react-native:version set from package.json: 7.8.0 (7,8,0 - 7008000)
:notifee_react-native:android.compileSdk using custom value: 33
:notifee_react-native:android.targetSdk using custom value: 33
:notifee_react-native:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:notifee_react-native:reactNativeAndroidDir D:\Repos\family_tracker\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.
Android gradle plugin: 7.4.2
Gradle: 8.0.1
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :react-native-ultimate-config
Using react-native dir from default location:D:\Repos\family_tracker\node_modules\react-native
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.
WARNING:The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (30.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 7.4.2.
Android SDK Build Tools 30.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :app:buildCodegenCLI SKIPPED
> Task :app:generateCodegenSchemaFromJavaScript SKIPPED
> Task :app:generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema SKIPPED
> Task :app:generatePackageList
> Task :app:preBuild
> Task :app:preDebugBuild
> Task :lottie-react-native:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :lottie-react-native:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :lottie-react-native:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :notifee_react-native:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :notifee_react-native:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :notifee_react-native:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-admob-native-ads:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-admob-native-ads:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-admob-native-ads:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-admob_admob:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-admob_admob:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-admob_admob:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-android-location-enabler:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-android-location-enabler:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-android-location-enabler:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-battery:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-battery:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-battery:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_async-storage:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_async-storage:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_clipboard:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_clipboard:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_clipboard:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_viewpager:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_viewpager:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_viewpager:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-contacts:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-contacts:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-contacts:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-date-picker:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-date-picker:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-date-picker:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-geocoder:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geocoder:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geocoder:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:assertNoMultipleInstances
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:preBuild
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:preDebugBuild
> Task :react-native-reanimated:assertLatestReactNativeWithNewArchitectureTask SKIPPED
> Task :react-native-reanimated:assertNoMultipleInstances
> Task :react-native-reanimated:assertNoReanimated2WithNewArchitectureTask SKIPPED
> Task :react-native-reanimated:preBuild
> Task :react-native-reanimated:preDebugBuild
> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-google-signin_google-signin:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-google-signin_google-signin:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-google-signin_google-signin:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-maps:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-navigation-bar-color:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-navigation-bar-color:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-navigation-bar-color:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-permissions:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-screens:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-svg:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-ultimate-config:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-ultimate-config:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-ultimate-config:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-video:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-video:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-video:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :realm:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :realm:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :realm:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :lottie-react-native:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :notifee_react-native:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-admob-native-ads:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-admob_admob:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-android-location-enabler:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-battery:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_async-storage:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_clipboard:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_viewpager:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-contacts:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-date-picker:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-geocoder:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-google-signin_google-signin:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-maps:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-navigation-bar-color:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-permissions:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-screens:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-svg:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-ultimate-config:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-video:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :realm:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :lottie-react-native:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :notifee_react-native:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-admob-native-ads:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-admob_admob:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-android-location-enabler:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-battery:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_async-storage:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_clipboard:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_viewpager:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-contacts:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-date-picker:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geocoder:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-google-signin_google-signin:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-navigation-bar-color:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-ultimate-config:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-video:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :realm:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :lottie-react-native:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :lottie-react-native:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :lottie-react-native:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :lottie-react-native:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :notifee_react-native:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :notifee_react-native:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :notifee_react-native:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :notifee_react-native:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-admob-native-ads:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-admob-native-ads:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-admob-native-ads:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-admob-native-ads:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-admob_admob:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-admob_admob:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-admob_admob:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-admob_admob:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-android-location-enabler:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-android-location-enabler:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-android-location-enabler:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-android-location-enabler:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-battery:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-battery:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-battery:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-battery:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_async-storage:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_async-storage:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_async-storage:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_async-storage:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_clipboard:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_clipboard:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_clipboard:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_clipboard:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_masked-view:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_netinfo:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_viewpager:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-community_viewpager:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_viewpager:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-community_viewpager:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-contacts:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-contacts:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-contacts:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-contacts:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-date-picker:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-date-picker:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-date-picker:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-date-picker:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geocoder:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-geocoder:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geocoder:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geocoder:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-geolocation-service:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-get-random-values:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-google-signin_google-signin:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-google-signin_google-signin:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-google-signin_google-signin:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-google-signin_google-signin:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-image-crop-picker:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-linear-gradient:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-maps:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-maps:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-navigation-bar-color:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-navigation-bar-color:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-navigation-bar-color:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-navigation-bar-color:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-permissions:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-permissions:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-reanimated:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-screens:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-screens:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-splash-screen:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-svg:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-svg:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-ultimate-config:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-ultimate-config:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-ultimate-config:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-ultimate-config:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-vector-icons:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-video:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :react-native-video:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-video:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :react-native-video:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :realm:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :realm:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :realm:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :realm:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
110 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 105 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

ERROR:D:\Repos\family_tracker\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\map-marker.png: Resource and asset merger: '-' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore
ERROR:D:\Repos\family_tracker\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\map-marker.png: Resource and asset merger: '-' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: D:\Repos\family_tracker\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\map-marker.png: Error: '-' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 31s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Comment: @IftikharHussainOrakzai I have added an answer.Please check if this solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the solution but a way to solve this.

First I run the command `npx react-native start` and then a to build the react-native application. and this issue comes.

To resolve this issue first run `npx react-native run-android` it will start the metro server  and I the metro server got close start it with the command `npx react-native start` and the press r.